# multi index json to data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading text file and forming json using python defaukt dict to create data frame and finally create parquet file.
I create pandas data frame  and
each row is uniquely identified by Time,source,event and meta_data column..there could other field like COL1, COL2..COl100.

I want to create Data frame like this

**DATAFRAME**

```
Time                       EVENT                      META_DATA        SOURCE COL1 COL2 COL3
20200508051804.8340+0730  event1                       some meta data  source1 10 23
```

To create above data frame i need to form the json like the below one

```
  d1={'100': {('event1','source1',"some meta data"): {'COL1': 10, 'COL1': 'some'}}}
    
  df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v).T for v in d1.values()], keys=d1.keys()).rename_axis(index=['Time', 'EVENT','source','meta_data']).reset_index()
```

It works fine, but for this to achieve, i need to maintain value for these attribute as tuple.
looking for alternate way of storing it
like i can store like this

```
d1={'100': {'source1': {'COL1': 10, 'COL1': 'some', 'COL3': 1.1}}, 'EVENT':'event1', 'meta_data':"some meta data"}
```

and still be able to create above DATAFRAME

UPDATE1:
Input:

```
d1={'100': {'source1': {'COL1': 10, 'COL2': '2.3', 'COL3': 1.1},'source2': {'COL1': 19, 'COL2': '3.4', 'COL4': 0.4}, 'EVENT':'event1', 'meta_data':"some metadata1"},'200': {'source1': {'COL1': 10, 'COL2': '0.55', 'COL4': 1.1},'source2': {'COL1': 11, 'COL4': '5.6', 'COL3': 1.1}, 'EVENT':'event2','meta_data':"some meta data2"},'300': {'source3': {'COL1': 15, 'COL2': '.23', 'COL4': 1.1},'source1': {'COL1': 10, 'COL4': '4.7', 'COL3':1.2}, 'EVENT':'event3', 'meta_data':"some meta data3"}}
```

Output:
pandas dataframe

```
 Time EVENT   META_DATA       SOURCE  COL1 COL2   COL3   COL4
100  event1   some meta data1  source1 10    2.3   1.1
100  event1   some meta data1  source2 19    3.4         0.4
200  event2   some meta data2  source1 10    0.55        1.1
200  event2   some meta data2  source2 11          1.1   5.6
300  event2   some meta data3  source3 15    .23         1.1
300  event2   some meta data3  source1 10          1.2   4.7
```

EVENT and META_DATA is time wise ie. would always be same for particular time.
Ex: Time 100 has event1 and meta data some meta data1.
There can multiple please source in a particular time and each source can be associated with one or more  (fields i.e COL1,COl2,....COL100).Each source should be in separate row.
Ex: source1, source 2 belongs to time 100

Comment: Not sure I follow. Do you have the json as input, and you're trying to create a dataframe - or vice versa? Specifically, what's the input and what's the expected output?

Comment: @Roy2012 updated the question

Comment: Thanks. Are you certain that the input and the output is accurate? The input contains EVENT':'some event', while the output is EVENT - event1. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @Roy2012 Thanks corrected it.

Comment: Is the source always called 'source1'? If not, can you add another example with a different source name? Do you know the set of source names in advance?

Comment: @Roy2012 updated the question..consider time field as integer for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1, orient="index").reset_index()
df = df.melt(id_vars = ["EVENT", "meta_data", "index"]).dropna()
df = pd.concat([df, df.value.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df.rename(columns = {"variable": "source"}).drop("value", axis=1)
```

The output is:

```
    EVENT        meta_data index   source  COL1  COL2  COL3 COL4
0  event1   some metadata1   100  source1    10   2.3   1.1  NaN
1  event2  some meta data2   200  source1    10  0.55   NaN  1.1
2  event3  some meta data3   300  source1    10   NaN   1.2  4.7
3  event1   some metadata1   100  source2    19   3.4   NaN  0.4
4  event2  some meta data2   200  source2    11   NaN   1.1  5.6
8  event3  some meta data3   300  source3    15   .23   NaN  1.1
```